# Identify enclosing loop of a block in LLVM

Tags: c++, c, llvm

For LLVM Basic Blocks, represented by class `BasicBlock`, how can I identify which nearest loop (if any) contains that block . And I want to identify this inside a `runOnModule` pass.

Answer (score 6):

You can register an LoopInfo dependency and use getLoopFor(BasicBlock *BB):

```
Loop* llvm::LoopInfo::getLoopFor(const BasicBlock *BB) const
```

You can check the documentation in: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfo.html#a4abca289c73cd09487e05d11d9f7d877